# android recyclerview scrolling accuratly to beginning of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can you make recyclerview to scroll in accurate beginning of each item when scrolling, like horizontal recyclerview in google play.

Comment: You might consider using `ViewPager`

Comment: `android.support.v7.widget.LinearSnapHelper` ?

Comment: @pskink thanks, i didn't know the snaphelper.

Comment: now you know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to implement google play app linear snapping functionality, the you could refer this tutorial [RecyclerView Snapping](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/09/android-tip-recyclerview-snapping-with.html)

it explains in detail to implement it

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    rvPreview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    rvPreview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

And use this

```
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvPreview);
```